# Functional way to add to Lists that are Class-Members

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I want to sort items of a class and collect them in Collection-Classes that beside a List-Member also contain further information that are necessary for the sorting process.

The following example is a a very simplified example for my problem. Although it doesn't make sense, I hope it still can help to understand my Question.

```
type ItemType = Odd|Even  //realworld: more than two types possible

type Item(number) =
    member this.number = number
    member this.Type = if (this.number % 2) = 0 then Even else Odd

type NumberTypeCollection(numberType:ItemType , ?items:List<Item>) =
    member this.ItemType =  numberType
    member val items:List<Item> = defaultArg items List.empty<Item> with get,set
    member this.append(item:Item) =  this.items <- item::this.items

let addToCollection (collections:List<NumberTypeCollection>) (item:Item) =
    let possibleItem =
        collections
        |> Seq.where (fun c -> c.ItemType = item.Type) //in my realworld code, several groups may be returned
        |> Seq.tryFind(fun _ -> true) 

    match possibleItem with
        |Some(f) -> f.append item
                    collections
        |None   -> NumberTypeCollection(item.Type, [item]) :: collections

let rec findTypes (collections:List<NumberTypeCollection>) (items:List<Item>) =
    match items with
    | [] -> collections
    | h::t -> let newCollections = ( h|> addToCollection collections)
                findTypes newCollections t


let items = [Item(1);Item(2);Item(3);Item(4)]

let finalCollections = findTypes List.empty<NumberTypeCollection> items
```

I'm unsatisfied with the ***addToCollection*** method, since it requires the items in **NumberTypeCollection** to be mutual. Maybe there are further issues.

What can be a proper functional solution to solve this issue?

Edit: I'm sorry. May code was too simplified. Here is a little more complex example that should hopefully illustrate why I chose the mutual class-member (although this could still be the wrong decision):

```
open System

type Origin = Afrika|Asia|Australia|Europa|NorthAmerika|SouthAmerica

type Person(income, taxrate, origin:Origin) =
    member this.income = income
    member this.taxrate = taxrate
    member this.origin = origin


type PersonGroup(origin:Origin , ?persons:List<Person>) =
    member this.origin = origin
    member val persons:List<Person> = defaultArg persons List.empty<Person> with get,set
    member this.append(person:Person) =  this.persons <- person::this.persons

//just some calculations to group people into some subgroups
let isInGroup (person:Person) (personGroup:PersonGroup) =
    let avgIncome =
        personGroup.persons 
        |> Seq.map (fun p -> float(p.income * p.taxrate) / 100.0)
        |> Seq.average
    Math.Abs ( (avgIncome / float person.income) - 1.0 ) < 0.5


let addToGroup (personGroups:List<PersonGroup>) (person:Person) =
    let possibleItem =
        personGroups
        |> Seq.where (fun p -> p.origin = person.origin)
        |> Seq.where (isInGroup person)
        |> Seq.tryFind(fun _ -> true) 

    match possibleItem with
        |Some(f) -> f.append person
                    personGroups
        |None   -> PersonGroup(person.origin, [person]) :: personGroups

let rec findPersonGroups (persons:List<Person>) (personGroups:List<PersonGroup>) =
    match persons with
    | [] -> personGroups
    | h::t -> let newGroup = ( h|> addToGroup personGroups)
              findPersonGroups t newGroup


let persons = [Person(1000,20, Afrika);Person(1300,22,Afrika);Person(500,21,Afrika);Person(400,20,Afrika)]

let c = findPersonGroups persons List.empty<PersonGroup>
```

What I may need to emphasize: *There can be several different groups with the same origin.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomas' solution using groupby is the optimal approach if you want to generate your collections only once, it's a simple and concise.

If you want to be able to add/remove items in a functional, referentially transparent style for this type of problem, I suggest you move away from `seq` and start using `Map`.

You have a setup which is fundamentally dictionary-like.  You have a unique key and a value.  The functional F# equivalent to a dictionary is a `Map`, it is an immutable data structure based on an AVL tree.  You can insert, remove and search in O(log n) time.  When you append/remove from the `Map`, the old `Map` is maintained and you receive a new `Map`.

Here is your code expressed in this style

```
type ItemType = 
    |Odd
    |Even

type Item (number) =
    member this.Number = number
    member this.Type = if (this.Number % 2) = 0 then Even else Odd

type NumTypeCollection = {Items : Map<ItemType, Item list>}

/// Functions on NumTypeCollection
module NumberTypeCollection =
    /// Create empty collection
    let empty = {Items = Map.empty}

    /// Append one item to the collection
    let append (item : Item) numTypeCollection =
        let key = item.Type
        match Map.containsKey key numTypeCollection.Items with
        |true ->
            let value = numTypeCollection.Items |> Map.find key
            let newItems = 
                numTypeCollection.Items
                |> Map.remove key 
                |> Map.add key (item :: value) // append item
            {Items = newItems }
        |false -> {Items = numTypeCollection.Items |> Map.add key [item]}

    /// Append a list of items to the collections
    let appendList (item : Item list) numTypeCollection =
        item |> List.fold (fun acc it -> append it acc) numTypeCollection
```

Then call it using:

```
let items = [Item(1);Item(2);Item(3);Item(4)]

let finalCollections = NumberTypeCollection.appendList items (NumberTypeCollection.empty)
```

Comment: This is a very good approach for my minimal example. Sadly I oversimplified it. There can be several groups of lists per ItemType. Your answer is correct, but my question was wrong.bb

Comment: @HorstLemke Is that beyond the edit you made a few minutes ago?  The code I suggest still seems to work for the new example you supplied just by changing `ItemType` to `Origin` and `Item` to `Person`.

Comment: With the new example it should be possible to have several Africa groups depending on the income of each group member. My Example-Code creates three Person-Groups with the same Origin Afrika. The second group has 2 Members, they have a similar income..

Comment: Now I see, maybe. PersGroupCollection allows this. It is a sequence with a map that always has one entry. I probably need some time to get this.

Comment: @HorstLemke Ah yes, I see now what you're getting at.  Was hard to spot the difference between the two examples at my first look.  I think you can still use an approach like this but maybe you need an extra level of types.  A `Map` of `Map`s, for instance.

Comment: @HorstLemke You could use `Map<Origin, Map<bool, Person list>>` or just `Map<Origin, Person list * Person List>` or make an extra collection that groups by income in and use it like `Map<Origin, IncomePersonGroup>`.  You have many possibilities depending on your design needs.

Comment: I now see my main problem, that I still think too much in objects. I should use more lists and records instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're trying to group the items by their type. The easiest way to do that is to use the standard library function `Seq.groupBy`. The following should implement the same logic as your code:

```
items
|> Seq.groupBy (fun item -> item.Type)
|> Seq.map (fun (key, values) ->
    NumberTypeCollection(key, List.ofSeq values))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe there are further issues.

Probably. It's difficult to tell, since it's hard to detect the purpose of the OP code... still:

**Why do you even need an `Item` class?** Instead, you could simply have a `itemType` function:

```
let itemType i = if i % 2 = 0 then Even else Odd
```

This function is [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency), which means that you can replace it with its value if you wish. That makes it as good as a property getter method, but now you've already saved yourself from introducing a new type.

**Why define a `NumberTypeCollection` class?** Why not a simple record?

```
type NumberTypeList = { ItemType : ItemType; Numbers : int list }
```

You can implement `addToCollection` like something like this:

```
let addToCollection collections i =
    let candidate =
        collections
        |> Seq.filter (fun c -> c.ItemType = (itemType i))
        |> Seq.tryHead
    match candidate with
    | Some x ->
        let x' = { x with Numbers = i :: x.Numbers }
        collections |> Seq.filter ((<>) x) |> Seq.append [x']
    | None ->
        collections |> Seq.append [{ ItemType = (itemType i); Numbers = [i] }]
```

Being immutable, it doesn't mutate the input `collections`, but instead returns a new sequence of `NumberTypeList`.

Also notice the use of `Seq.tryHead` instead of `Seq.tryFind(fun _ -> true)`.

Still, if you're attempting to group items, then Tomas' suggestion of using `Seq.groupBy` is more appropriate.